# Switch inside navigation drawer in android

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-switch

I have a Switch inside a navigation drawer.Toggle happens only on tap.When i try to slide and toggle the Switch, the navigation drawer slides.What do i do?

```
Switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton v,
                    boolean isChecked) {
                //switched
}
});
```

Comment: did you find a solution to the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code on your DrawerLayout :

```
    settingsSwitch.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if((event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) || (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN))
                drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_OPEN);
            else
                drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
            return false;
        }
    });
```